# WHM / CPANEL Server migration

Tags: cpanel, whm

Sorry about English, Actually i have been looking for best article about WHM/CPANEL server migration but i could not find yet. Hope this is the right platform.
I have one WHM/CPANEL server running with CentOS x86_64 standard. Now i want to migrate all stuff to my new high end machine.
Need to Transfer: (All accounts along with databases, Exim configuration, Tweak settings, PHP etc etc).
Note: I need step by step guide which will be highly appreciated, I am not too much technical and in learning phase so please go easy on me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install and setup cPanel on your new server.

After that you can migrate your all cPanel account to new server through transfer tool. WHM >> Transfers >> Transfer Tool

Here are the some useful docs.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Move+All+cPanel+Accounts+from+One+Server+to+Another

cPanel setting are stored in /etc/wwwacct.conf and /var/cpanel/cpanel.config file so you can copy that setting to new server.

Answer (score 0):

After the server setup is complete, you will have to recreate all the accounts you wish to move, on the server. You can create the domains in your server using the WHM and then restore the website contents manually using a FTP client(say FileZilla).

First you have to take the backup of your domain via cPanel. Please check below URL to find information regarding this:-

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/BackupWizard#Backup your entire site

Then Create the account in WHM.

Upload the contents in these newly created domain and restore them via WHM or cPanel.

To restore via WHM please follow below steps:-

Main >> Backup >> Restore a Full Backup/cpmove file

Please refer the cPanel docs link below on how to restore an account via cPanel.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/BackupWizard#

Answer (score 0):

If you have cpanel WHM server and you want to transfer your whole server accounts and websites to another WHM server then its really very easy and simple. All you need is root access of both server.

If you have set up your high end new WHM server, then login to your new WHM with root user and go to transfer tool from WHM > Transfers > Transfer Tool. It will show you fields to input the details of your low end server. Once you provide the root information of server it will fetch the accounts lists and account details. From there you can select which accounts to transfer and which to not. If you want to transfer all accounts then you can select all and proceed the transfer. It will transfer all your accounts with their current package details.

Try the cpanel transfer tool its easy and simple to understand and proceed.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Move+All+cPanel+Accounts+from+One+Server+to+Another

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Transfer+Tool